# Terraform List of Maps

Tags: terraform

I currently have a single resource defined for

> aws_ebs_volume & aws_volume_attachment

I use a count based on a variable to determine how many devices I want to created followed by a count on the attachment:

```
data_volumes = ["50"]
data_device = ["xvde"]

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "datavolumes" {
  count             = "${length(var.data_volumes)}"
  size              = "${var.data_volumes[count.index]}"
  tags              = "${var.instance_tags}"
  encrypted         = "true"
  availability_zone = "us-east-2b"
  kms_key_id        = "${var.kms_key}"
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "attachvolumes" {
  count       = "${length(var.data_volumes)}"
  device_name = "${var.data_device[count.index]}"
  volume_id   = "${aws_ebs_volume.datavolumes.*.id[count.index]}"
  instance_id = "${aws_instance.general.id}"
}
```

I'm struggling with finding a way to assign unique tags to each of these volumes that get created, as you can see I'm using a static list of "instance_tags" for each of the volumes but I'd like to have unique tags applied to each of the volumes.  I'm trying to avoid having to specify a resource/volume but might be easiest at this point.

Hoping someone can help me understand if its possible and an example of what it looks like.

Comment: What does `var.instance_tags` look like? Can you also show what your current code results in and what you want as a resulting output?

Comment: `instance_tags {
  Name          = "TUE2AINFGEN10"
  Environment   = "TST"
  Criticality   = "3"
  Application   = "General"
  AppType       = "Geneal"
  BusinessOwner = "Platform"
  ITOwner       = "Role-IT-PlatformTeam"
  ManagedBy     = "Terraform"
  InformationClassification = ""
}
`I'd like to be able to change the tag values for some of those tags based on the iteration of the EBS volume that we are configuring.  Example for one volume might be: `instance_tags {
  VolumeLabel           = "Data"
  VolumeLetter          = "E:"
}`

Comment: Where does `VolumeLabel = "Data"` come from there? Or should it always have that tag?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, those are an example of a set of tags that I’d like applied to just one of the volumes that the resource would iterate through.  Similar to how the resource has the ability to go through my list of sizes or list or how I can have it iterate through my list of device names, I’d like to have a way for it to iterate through a “list of maps” to apply different sets of tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an approach that works for what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "datavolumes" {
  count = "${length(var.data_volumes)}"
  size  = "${var.data_volumes[count.index]}"
  tags = "${merge(
    var.instance_tags,
    map(
      "DriveLetter", "${var.data_letters[count.index]}",
      "DriveLabel", "${var.data_labels[count.index]}"
    )
  )}"

data_volumes = ["50","50","50"]
data_device = ["xvde","xvdf","xvdg"]
data_letters = ["E:", "F:", "G:"]
data_labels = ["Data", "Logs", "TempDB"]
```

This gives me unique EBS volumes with Unique tag properties for each volumes and maintains my single resource

Comment: terraform will spit an error since it's a expecting a string and you're passing a list for data_volumes